# Restructuring loop logic and its effect on allocations

Tags: memory-optimization, julia

I came across in a code base `# TODO this seems very clumsy to duplicate the loop code like this?` so I figured I'd give it a shot as a learning exercise. I'd like some feedback on what I came up with, particularly:

1. Is this proper idiomatic Julia, or close? Or am I just writing Python in Julia?
2. What explains the difference in allocations between the two approaches?
   (Arguments used: `[1,1], octaves=10`)

   - `Old: 0.000013 seconds (63 allocations: 1.062 KiB)`
   - `New: 0.000008 seconds (41 allocations: 1.500 KiB)`

Thanks!

Original function:

```
# coords is [x] or [x, y] or [x, y, z] or [x, y, z, w]
function _octaves(coords::Array{T, 1} where T <: Real;
        octaves::Int = 1,
        persistence=1.0)
    total     = 0.0
    frequency = 1.0
    amplitude = 1.0
    maxval    = 0.0
    # TODO this seems very clumsy to duplicate the loop code like this?
    l = length(coords)
    if l == 1
        for i in 1:octaves
            total += simplexnoise(coords[1] * frequency) * amplitude
            maxval += amplitude
            amplitude *= persistence
            frequency *= 2
        end
    elseif l == 2
        for i in 1:octaves
            total += simplexnoise(coords[1] * frequency, coords[2] * frequency) * amplitude
            maxval += amplitude
            amplitude *= persistence
            frequency *= 2
        end
    elseif l == 3
        for i in 1:octaves
            total += simplexnoise(coords[1] * frequency, coords[2] * frequency, coords[3] * frequency) * amplitude
            maxval += amplitude
            amplitude *= persistence
            frequency *= 2
        end
    elseif l == 4
        for i in 1:octaves
            total += simplexnoise(coords[1] * frequency, coords[2] * frequency, coords[3] * frequency, coords[4] * frequency) * amplitude
            maxval += amplitude
            amplitude *= persistence
            frequency *= 2
        end
    end
    return total / maxval
end
```

And my refactor:

```
function _octaves(coords::Array{T, 1} where T <: Real;
        octaves::Int = 1,
        persistence=1.0)     
    total     = 0.0
    frequency = 1.0 
    amplitude = 1.0
    maxval    = 0.0

    for _ in 1:octaves
        inputs = coords .* frequency
        total += simplexnoise(inputs...) * amplitude

        maxval += amplitude
        amplitude *= persistence
        frequency *= 2
    end

    return total / maxval
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very idomatic, in principle.  The loop refactoring is exactly what I would have done.

Here's some other suggestions:

```
const Coords{T} = NTuple{N, T} where N

function _octaves(coords::Coords{T}; octaves::Int=1, persistence::T=one(T)) where {T<:Real}
    if octaves < 1
        # prevent zero division
        throw(DomainError(octaves, "`octaves` must be at least 1!"))
    end

    total = zero(T)
    maxval = zero(T)

    for octave in 1:octaves
        p = octave - 1
        frequency = 2 ^ p
        amplitude = persistence ^ p

        maxval += amplitude

        scaled_coords = coords .* frequency
        total += simplexnoise(scaled_coords...) * amplitude
    end

    return total / maxval
end
```

1. Using `one` and `zero` to ensure **type stability** (a very important concept, which you should read about if you don't know it!)
2. Replacing some intermediate updates by explicit powers.  The calculation of `frequency` is trivial to the compiler, since it is an integer power of 2.  `amplitude` might do some unnecessary work; I think it is clearer that way, and not worth the microoptimisation, but you'd have to test that for your use case.

The choice of type for `coords` is really determined by the rest of the code.  If this is only ever going to be used for coordinates of bounded dimension, I'd very much prefer a tuple as I wrote above.  If you use vectors all the way down (this looks a bit like signal processing?), then staying with `Coords{T} = Vector{T}` is easier.

While not part of the question, it might be nicer to have `simplenoise` work on an iterable, not a varargs argument.  Possibly even as `simplenoise(frequency, coords)`, then the allocation of `scaled_coords` is removed.

If there's any chance that the summation will overflow, take a look at [`Base.widen`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.widen).  Also, you might want to ensure that `octaves < 8 * sizeof(Int)` or something like that, and add this to the check at the beginning.

If this is really the hot part of some code to be optimized, with `octaves` being constant over many calls, there's the possibility to write a `@generated` function to unroll the loop completely, but unless it is critical, it's not worth it.

---

As for the difference in benchmarking: first, you should do that with [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl), not `@time`.  Then, I haven't measured myself, but it's quite surely due to the intermediate `inputs` array you construct.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Looks like I have some reading lined up for tonight, I really appreciate you taking the time.